# How can I use testdisk & photorec to recover all jpg files?

Tags: testdisk

http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step

I am sorry the documentation is kind of overwhelming for me.

My purpose is just recover jpg files...

I tried many times but it was recovering other files, and it seems hangs in the middle in my attempts..

Comment: This can take hours if not days. Are you sure it's hanging and not just busy searching without results for a long time?

Comment: So, in order to make it faster, I guess the performance would be improved if there are options or scripts to skip other rubbish and just focus on jpg.

Answer (score 3):

At the bottom of the second screen with partitions arrow over to [File Opt] and there is an option to filter for jpg files only.

Comment: unfortunately there is no option for only Python .py files.. has .pyc, but no .py for some reason

Comment: https://git.cgsecurity.org/cgit/testdisk/tree/src/file_txt.c suggests that `.py` and many other plain text file formats are subsumed under `.txt` in the format selection and the correct extension will be applied if the script starts with a specific string, e.g. `#!/usr/bin/env python` in case of `.py`.

Comment: @JoachimWagner   I've switched over to NFTS for data partitions with symlinks. NTFS has directory information in its file journal, so it can recover directory structure. Much easier to undelete a whole directory. `ntfsundelete` `apt install ntfsprogs` or ntfs-3g. Probably only using ext4 for root partition now.

Comment: Still you can only undelete what is not yet overwritten. You may want to look into log-structured filesystems or use automatic snapshots, e.g. opensuse's btrfs+snapper can be configured to take hourly snapshots.

Comment: @JoachimWagner, yes, that is a given. Id have to look into LogFS or LinLogFS, or I could just use NTFS which also works with Windows.